# Select XML node based on value of sibling node

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have a VB.NET 2013 program that reads from/writes to an xml document and I'm trying to figure out how to access a specific node when I know the text of one of the node's siblings. I've seen other posts that are **similar** to what I'm trying to do, but my xml structure is slightly different and I'm not sure how to apply those solutions to my document.

Here's a sample of my xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Books>
  <Book>
    <Title>Hansel and Gretel</Title>
    <Pages>221</Pages>
    <Price>3.5</Price>
    <Author>Grimm</Author>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Title>Green Eggs and Ham</Title>
    <Pages>145</Pages>
    <Price>5.25</Price>
    <Author>Dr. Seuss</Author>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

The examples I've seen in other posts have values in the node name `<Title title="Green Eggs and Ham">`. As you can see, mine doesn't.

I can't figure out how to use XPath, XPathNavigator, etc for my xml document to find a price, for instance if I know the title.

I see a lot of examples that look like: `/Books/Book[@Title="Green Eggs and Ham"]`, and I tried using that with XPathNavigator.SelectSingleNode(), but I can't figure out the correct VB.Net/XPath syntax to use with my xml format.

**UPDATE** (Example answer)
Since I'm using this in a VB.NET project, I needed to know how to use the examples that Bogdan and ThW gave. Using my sample XML I did this to get the number of pages for the title "Hansel and Gretel":

```
Dim xpathDoc As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument([path_to_xml)
Dim xmlNav as XPathNavigator = xpathDoc.CreateNavigator()
Dim pages as String

pages = xmlNav.SelectSingleNode("/Books/Book[Title='Hansel and Gretel']/Pages").Value
```

Which, of course, returns "221"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@` in XPath ist a shortcut for `attribute::`. It selects attributes nodes (or more specific nodes on the attributes axis).

Your `Title` node is an element node. It is a child of the `Book` element node. `child` is the default axis, so it is optional. Basically `/Books/Book` is short for `/child::Books/child::Book`.

The part in `[]` is a condition for the nodes. `[@Title="Green Eggs and Ham"]` filters the node for an attribute `Title` with the given value.

To look for the child element node `Title` remove the `@`.

`/Books/Book[Title="Green Eggs and Ham"]`

Comment: Great detailed explanation, ThW. Thanks! How do I use that in VB.NET code, then?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Book/Title[text()='Green Eggs and Ham']/../Price
```

`text()` searches in value. `..` selects parent element

**EDIT**

Thanks ThW for explanation about `.`, removed from answer.

Comment: `text()` selects the text child nodes, `.` the current node. So `text()` compares each text child node with the string, `.` compares the text content of the current node.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Bogdan, but can you put that code in the context of a sample VB.NET line? How do I use that in VB.NET code?